# Unpack List with key value pair

Tags: python

I need to get the value(the right hand value after the colon) in this list
`list = [apple:tuesday, banana:wednesday, guava:thursday]`

Comment: That's not a valid Python list. You're probably talking about a dictionary. Please provide some code of what you tried, what happened, what did you expect to happen? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure this is a list ? ```list = [apple:tuesday, banana:wednesday, guava:thursday]```, that looks like a dictionary

Comment: Yes that's the list I got back from my output. Might just have to go to its implementation and add the quotation marks and eveything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

first your list will be like

```
     list1=["apple:tuesday", "banana:wednesday", "guava:thursday"]
     k=0
     
     for i in list1:
        x=i.split(":")
        print(x)
        
        list1[k]=x[1]
        k+=1


     print(list1)
```

i hope this is what you were trying to do

Comment: Yeah, but using inbuilt functions like ```list``` is a serious mistake. Name it something else or it can cause you problems

Comment: Yes, I already got it running like this when i added my quotation marks, but I get my list back like this ```list = [apple:tuesday, banana:wednesday, guava:thursday]``` so above implementation doesn't work. Might have to go fix the list packing to include the quotation if there is no way around it.

Comment: but the list you gave will give invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by list comprehension.it's easy and fast

```py
l = ["apple:tuesday", "banana:wednesday", "guava:thursday"]
new_l = [item.split(":")[1] for item in l]
```

list comprehension work like this

```py
l = [i for i in range(5)]
# l = [0,1,2,3,4]
```